# is there a specified way to get this expansion?

Tags: beta-function

$\beta(x,y-1)=\beta(x,y)+\beta(x+1,y)+\beta(x+2,y)........$
i have tried to find the proof of this formula on google and some books  but i found other methods like this MSE post [Beta function series expansion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2275702/beta-function-series-expansion)
 and can not understand them can anyone help me and give me a simple method to prove it via gamma function or another method

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align*}
\beta(x,y)+&\beta(x+1,y)+\beta(x+2,y)+\cdots\\
&= \beta(x,y)+\frac{x}{(x+y)}\beta(x,y)+\frac{x(x+1)}{(x+y)(x+y+1)}\beta(x,y)+\cdots\\
&=\beta(x,y)\left[1+\frac{x}{x+y}+\frac{x(x+1)}{(x+y)(x+y+1)}+\cdots\right]\\
&=\beta(x,y)\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(x)_k}{(x+y)_k},\qquad (x)_k=x(x+1)\cdots(x+k-1)\\
&=\beta(x,y)\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(1)_k(x)_k}{k! (x+y)_k},\qquad (1)_k=k!\\
&=\beta(x,y) {}_2F_1(1,x;x+y;1)\\
&=\beta(x,y)\frac{\Gamma(x+y)\Gamma(y-1)}{\Gamma(x+y-1)\Gamma(y)},\quad using~Gauss’~summation~ formula\\
&=\frac{\Gamma(x)\Gamma(y)}{\Gamma(x+y)}\frac{\Gamma(x+y)\Gamma(y-1)}{\Gamma(x+y-1)\Gamma(y)},\qquad for ~\beta(x,y)=\frac{\Gamma(x)\Gamma(y)}{\Gamma(x+y)}\\
&=\frac{\Gamma(x)\Gamma(y-1)}{\Gamma(x+y-1)}=\beta(x,y-1).
\end{align*}

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! At the moment, it is hard to understand your answer. Please consider adding further context, and formatting your post using MathJax. [This page](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020) should give you a start at learning how to typeset mathematics here so that your posts say what you want them to, and also look good.